# Can we use jQuery to work with Java objects OR does it manipulate DOM model only?

Tags: java, jquery, json, dom, servlets

I have a very complex scenario where i need to change the java objects(basically HashMap ) from jquery get Request and get the response and print that in the jsp. User can send number of request and get seperate response from servlet based on request and display the data.

after every request i have to put the map in session and than in another request i get the same in session and do the updates and put it back in session.

```
JqueryGet(parameter) to Java.    
Updating Hashmap according to parameter.
Putting hashmap in session . ( session.setAttribute("map",map))
sending response back to Jsp in jquery and print results in jsp.
Than another request send to Java .
it will get the map from session session.getAttribute("map",map) and than update the map based on new request .
Put the map again in session and so on....Than i have a submit button finally which will show the new data on the page and than update the server.
```

Is this the right approach ? My functionality is working fine as of now in Dev environment. But i am worried whether i should use DOM. if i will use DOM it will be very complex since i have to manipulate much values of Hashmap based on request.

Here is the jquery code :

```
 $.ajax({
                 url: '<%=portalContext.createTemplateProcessURI()%>'
                 +'?s1='+ $("#networkBox1").val()+'&box1=Box1&tick=add&val1='+ allvs+'&s2='+ $("#networkBox2").val()+'&box2=Box2&val2='+ allvs,
                 type: 'get',
                 dataType: 'text',
                 async: false,
                 success: function(data) {                      
                        Processbox(data);   // This function displaying the result.
                  } 
              });
```

Answer (score 0):

dude, first of all, I think after you get your data from back end side, your java object has already changed to json object. I think your flow has no problem, because once you change to DOM, then all the data is send through front side but not back end side, if you use session, actually you handle your data at back end side, for me, I prefer the second one.

Here is my idea:

1.set a dom object in your page with the data get from your ajax

```
$(domId).val(value get from ajax);
```

2.If your don't want to show the data, use hidden type input in your jsp form

```
<input type="hidden" id="domId" name="domName">
```

3.once you click submit button, handle your data in your servlet

```
String data = request.getParameter("domName");
session.setAttributes("sessionData", data);
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: btw can you send your code sample to let me know more instead of just plain text

Comment: Thanks ..I have pasted my jquerycode .Please see. My java code is very vast , i can not paste that sorry. BUT to be specific it it getting the request paramters which u saw in jquery code and than updating the map with those values and than putting that map in session.setAttribute("map",map) and send response back. This process repeats until user wants to manipulate the data . Once user done he will click on submit button.